# Conditional subset in data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame in R that looks like this:

```
Id   group   category number
001  1       A        0.10
001  1       B        0.15
002  2       A        0.55
003  3       A        0.75
003  3       B        0.45
```

Now, I would like to have only one row per `Id`. For Id's in `groups` 1 and 2, the row which `category` is B should primarily be used. If there for `groups` 1 or 2 are no rows where the `category` is B, then `category` A should be used. For `Id's` which `group` is 3, the row where the `category` is A should always be used.

The output should look like this

```
Id   group   category number
001  1       B        0.15
002  2       A        0.55
003  3       A        0.75
```

How could this be done in R?

Comment: Sorry - didn't read carefully and missed the different rules for different groups bit. Edited my answer and it should work now.

Comment: @Falcc I think either your description or the expected output is not correct.  For 'Id' 3, you have 'A', 'B' as category and by the description, the row with category 'B' should be used.  Can you please clarify

Comment: @GregorThomas, thank you for the answer. For some reason, that didn't unfortunately work. However, I think your first answer could work if I first remove all rows where group is 3 and category is B. Could you please write that suggestion again, since I didn't have time to try that?

Comment: @akrun For Id 3, the row where category is A should always be used, as explained in the last sentence.

Comment: Sure, I'll revert the edits on my answer and add that filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `B` comes after `A`, we'll sort by category descending and keep one row per group, filtering out the group 3 / category A rows per your suggestion.

```
library(dplyr) 
your_data %>%
  filter(!(group == 3 & category == "A")) %>%
  group_by(Id, group) %>%
  arrange(desc(category)) %>%
  slice(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `slice`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(Id) %>%
   slice(max(match('B', category, nomatch = 0), 1))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Id = c("001", "001", "002", "003", "003"), group = c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), category = c("A", "B", "A", "A", "B"), number = c(0.1, 
0.15, 0.55, 0.75, 0.45)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```